# is there any big difference of performance?? when using TCP Socket I/O code

Tags: java

when using TCP Socket I/O code.. Is there any big difference of performance between below two codes..?? The result of both is the same~~

```
        // -------- 1 -------- //
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

        // -------- 2 -------- //
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be. Quoting [**the doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29):

> **public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)**
>
> Creates a new PrintWriter from an existing OutputStream. *This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate OutputStreamWriter*, which will convert
> characters into bytes using the default character encoding.

In other words, a fresh `OutputStreamWriter` object is created in both cases of yours.

Comment: Oh~~ thank you for answering...!! ^_^ finally there is no difference.. right~?